# Where is lftp lockfile located?

Tags: backup

It seems that I have a left over lockfile for lftp somewhere in my Ubuntu 22.04. I need help to locate it.

Comment: lftp does not have a setting for a "lock file" When lftp sees parts of a file on the other end it will do a resume of that file. Your lock problem probably stems from something other than lftp.

Comment: This is right. After fixing other problems with the script the lock file problem vanished.

Comment: Please make it in answer if you believe others might benefit from it :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems right that lftp does not have a lockfile. After having fixed other backup problems the error of a lock for lftp disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

`$ locate *.lock`

*Required:

`sudo apt install mlocate` and a following

`sudo updatedb` to get the database initialized immediately.*

NOTE: This will find many lock files, depending on what you have running, or did run.